# Postgres FIFO query calculate profit margin

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor

I am working on my inventory system query to calculate profit based on FIFO (First-In-First-Out) in PostgreSQL (9.3+). Most of the replies are targeted for MS SQL Server so I am not sure how to go about it for PostgreSQL. I have tried using the Windows functions but am getting stuck at calculating the profit (I'm not sure if we need/can use cursors as I have not used them before)

- Sales (negative quantity) are around (20*4 + 30*1) = 110
- Cost of Goods sold based on FIFO are (5*2 + 10*2 + 10*1) = 40
- Profit should be 110 - 40 = 70

I have till now managed to calculate running totals. Could someone help with this?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/50b12/6

```
product_id product_name product_price purchase_date        product_quantity
1          Notebook     5             2017-05-05 00:00:00  2
1          Notebook     10            2017-05-06 00:00:00  4
1          Notebook     15            2017-05-07 00:00:00  6
1          Notebook     20            2017-05-08 00:00:00  -4 (this is sale)
1          Notebook     30            2017-05-09 00:00:00  -1 (this is sale)
```

Desired results should display the Sales and profit margin. As long as I can get the profit margin it would fix my issue.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in the question* as text tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *,
    sum(price_sold - price_purchased) over(order by rn) as profit 
from
    (
        select 
            row_number() over(order by purchase_date, product_id) as rn,
            product_id, product_price as price_purchased
        from inv_test, generate_series(1, abs(product_quantity))
        where product_quantity > 0
    ) p
    full join
    (
        select
            row_number() over(order by purchase_date, product_id) as rn,
            product_id, product_price as price_sold
        from inv_test, generate_series(1, abs(product_quantity))
        where product_quantity < 0
    ) s using (rn, product_id)
;
 rn | product_id | price_purchased | price_sold | profit 
----+------------+-----------------+------------+--------
  1 |          1 |               5 |         20 |     15
  2 |          1 |               5 |         20 |     30
  3 |          1 |              10 |         20 |     40
  4 |          1 |              10 |         20 |     50
  5 |          1 |              10 |         30 |     70
  6 |          1 |              10 |            |     70
  7 |          1 |              15 |            |     70
  8 |          1 |              15 |            |     70
  9 |          1 |              15 |            |     70
 10 |          1 |              15 |            |     70
 11 |          1 |              15 |            |     70
 12 |          1 |              15 |            |     70
```

Comment: Hi, I am doing the same FIFO calculation using MySql. In my case, I have to calculate FIFO COGS on the insertion to the table inventory_manager. The order of the purchase and sale will depend on the date of entry (to do the back date entries of sales & purchase).  This means if we have entries till 27-Oct-2017 and someone does back date entry of 1-Oct-2017, then all the COGS and available stock entry after 1-Oct-2017 should be re-calculated.

Comment: Schema of inventory manager is as follows:-                                    
   CREATE TABLE `inventory_manager` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL, -- Sales_Date or Purchase_Date
  `quantity` double NOT NULL, -- +ve for purchase, -ve for sales
  `rate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `available_quantity` double NOT NULL, -- For Closing Stock
  `fifo_cogs` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: I see 2 problems with this solution related to `generate_series`:

- can be slow if quantity is a huge number (e.g. billions of tiny items)
- won't work if quantity is fractional  (e.g. grams, liters, etc)